# What is you looking for? Emphatic

Tags: subject-verb-agreement

Is okay to use **'is'** instead of **'are'** in the case of singular **'you'** when we want to make it emphatic?

- Hey, I told you not to come here, didn't i? What **is** you doing here then?
- I spent all morning cooking! **Is** you going to eat it or what?
- You've got anything you need! What else **is** you looking for?
- I'm sick and tired of your games, it's all the same every day! When **is** you ever going to stop doing that?

Comment: Maybe if you add _it_ after is, as in _What is it you('re) doing here?_.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, all of the examples you've given are ungrammatical in standard English.  You'll need to follow the usual rules for subject–verb agreement:

> What **are** you doing here?
>   **Are** you going to eat it or not?
>   What **are** you looking for here?
>   When **are** you going to stop that?

These don't sound any more or less emphatic, but they do sound grammatical and natural.

Answer (score 1):

I am not clear what you mean by making it emphatic.

From a grammatical perspective all the above sentences are incorrect. You need to use only "are" in the above ones. There is no use for "you is" in English language.

["You are" vs "you is" when "you" is used as both singular and plural?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/5108/you-are-vs-you-is-when-you-is-used-as-both-singular-and-plural)